# Get specific word from string

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0

I've `Table URL` and I'd like select `Table Name` only. What is the best approach to achieve it?

URLs:

```
"db://SQL Table.Table.[dbo].[DirectoryType]" 
"db://SQL Table.Table.[dbo].[IX_AnalysisResult_ConceptVariations]" 
"db://SQL Table.Table.[dbo].[IX_AnalysisResult_DocXConcepts]"
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
DirectoryType
IX_AnalysisResult_ConceptVariations
IX_AnalysisResult_DocXConcepts
```

NOTE: These URLs will have `db://SQL Table.Table.[dbo].` in common most of the time so I am using following code to achieve this:

CODE:

```
var trimURL = tableURL.Replace("db://SQL Table.Table.[dbo].", String.Empty).Replace("[",String.Empty).Replace("]",String.Empty);
```

OUTPUT:

```
DirectoryType
IX_AnalysisResult_ConceptVariations
IX_AnalysisResult_DocXConcepts
```

If for some reason URL prefix is changed then my code won't work. So what is the best way to get a table name from these type of URLs?

Comment: Why you don't use [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? you can make a pattern and match names through it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the last index of '[' and ']' and get the substring therein:

```
var startIndex = tableUrl.LastIndexOf('[') + 1; // +1 to start after opening bracket
var endIndex = tableUrl.LastIndexOf(']');
var charsToRead = (startIndex - endIndex) - 1; // -1 to stop before closing bracket

var tableName = tableUrl.Substring( startIndex, charsToRead );
```

Of course, this assumes you can guarantee no brackets in your table name.

References:
[String.Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx)
[String.LastIndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It may be faster to skip the second find (the closing brace), assuming your format dictates it's always the last character in the line.  You can use `String.Length` instead of `LastIndexOf(']')`.

[String.Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to match the last thing inside the last group of `[]` that appears immediately at the end of a string:

```
\[([^\[^\]]*)\]$
```

At input `db://SQL Table.Table.[dbo].[DirectoryType]` you grab the string `DirectoryType`.

The `$` symbol means the end of a string.

You can see it in action [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B(%5B%5E%5C%5B%5E%5C%5D%5D*)%5C%5D%24&i=db%3A%2F%2FSQL%20Table.Table.%5Bdbo%5D.%5BDirectoryType%5D&o=s).

An example:

```
var match = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\[([^\[^\]]*)\]$", RegexOptions.Singleline);
Match match_result = match.Match("db://SQL Table.Table.[dbo].[DirectoryType]");
string result = "";
if (match_result.Groups.Count > 1)
    result = match_result.Groups[1].Value;
    //result = "DirectoryType"
```

Remember `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var matcher = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^.*\[(?<table>.*?)\]""$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var results = matcher.Match(/*your input string*/);
```

Inspect the results in the debugger and you'll find how to extract what you are looking for.

Note that this pattern assumes that your data actually includes the quotation marks shown in your question.

Answer (score 0):

you were doing it right, i just used `split` on `'.'`, I am assuming your url contains minimum `anything.[DirectoryType]"`

```
string op = tableURL.Split('.')[tableURL.Split('.').Length - 1].Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
```